# How to test concurrent logins using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am able to do a login test with a single user. If I want to do this for concurrent logins, I am told to use a [CSV Data Config](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) component, so I followed [this advice](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/best-practices#user_variables):

1. Create a text file containing the user names and passwords, separated by commas. Put this in the same directory as your test plan.
2. Add a CSV DataSet configuration element to the test plan. Name the variables USER and PASS.
3. Add a path to the filename in that element (I made sure to check the file path).
4. Replace the login name with `${USER}` and the password with `${PASS}` on the Log in (HTTP Request) Sampler.

Sadly, in my login page, I see `${USER}` and `${PASS}`, instead of the values they represent (those in the CSV file). What am I missing?

Comment: I seriously don't know what I missed, because it now works. I just know that I messed here and there with the jmx file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either jmeter is not finding your files or you have a typo somewhere.

In step no2 : be sure that your "user,pass" are exactly like in the file.

If in the file there a space and you dont in jmeter, he won't find the value, if you have a space in jmeter, he wont found the value. I usally go "user,pass" in the file and jmeter and it work fine.

Like this :

**in my csv** : myuser,mypass

**in jmeter**

[image]

In step no3 : I usally put the csv file in the root of where the jmeter test is, that way it always find it.

Comment: You might have missed my comment, where I mentioned that the problem got fixed. Thanks though. It was probably a typo.